# Automatically change OneNote page background to dark/black?

Tags: macros, microsoft-onenote

I have Onetastic for ON2013, whenever I make a new page I use that addon to make the page background black/blue (000009), and then whenever I type I need to manually change the text to white. Is there any way to automate the stylization in this regard when creating a new page in a specific note book? I was thinking about Onetastic macros but I'm not at all experienced in office macros so I'm not sure if I should be heading down this path.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like this:

- [Download](https://getonetastic.com/downloadFile&fv=0&file=OnetasticInstaller.x86.exe) and install Onetastic Add-On (you already have this, I didn't when looking for an answer to the problem)
- [Download](https://getonetastic.com/downloadMacro&id=D93A0B7D28D84AD69E68842FB07304F4) and install black background macro
- Open OneNote and in Home tab in your Ribbon, select `Background` -> `Blackboard page`

This will change both, your page background and your pen colors.